# Can you write folder actions with javascript (jxa)?

Tags: automation, applescript, javascript-automation

I am looking for a direct translation of AppleScript's

```
on adding folder items to this_folder
```

but I can't seem to find it anywhere, neither the usage of the terms or the keyword this_folder itself.

Answer (score 1):

Using Automator I could build a Folder Action workflow to display the path of a file moved to a folder using only JavaScript:

```
function run(input, parameters) {
   var app = Application.currentApplication();
   app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
   var text = "FileName = " + input[0];
   var options = { };
   app.displayAlert(text, options);

   return input;
}
```

I hope that could help.

Answer (score 0):

Folder Actions are defined in Standard Additions. The full syntax for this action is:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
```

You JXA script should look ***something*** like this:

```
app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true

function addingFolderItemsTo(this_folder, {afterReceiving:added_items})
{
    app.beep(2)
   // your code here uses this_folder and/or added_items
}
```

Parameters:

`this_folder` is an alias to the receiving folder.

`added_items` is a list of aliases for the dropped items.

Comment: sadly it didn't :'(

Comment: The function signature should be `addingFolderItemsTo(this_folder, added_items)`; but that still doesn't work.